# CodeChef : Time Limit Exceeded by the following java code

Tags: java

Here is the link to the problem  : - http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST/

Following is the code : -

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class INTEST {
    public static void main(String...s) {
        String str = "";
        try {
            str = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in )).readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        String[] ar = str.split(" ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(ar[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(ar[1]);
        int count = 0;
        if (k <= 10000000) {
            int[] t = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
                try {
                    t[i] = Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in )).readLine());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (t[i] <= 1000000000) {
                    if (t[i] % k == 0) count++;

                } else break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

I changed from Scanner to BufferedReader to read data but it could'nt help to reduce time.

Any help how can i reduce the time. Thanks.

The Problem :

The purpose of this problem is to verify whether the method you are using to read input data is sufficiently fast to handle problems branded with the enormous Input/Output warning. You are expected to be able to process at least 2.5MB of input data per second at runtime.

Input

The input begins with two positive integers n k (n, k<=10^7). 
The next n lines of input contain one positive integer ti, not greater than 10^9, each.

Output

Write a single integer to output, denoting how many integers ti are divisible by k.
Example

Input:
7 3

1

51

966369

7

9

999996

11

Output:

4

Comment: i just clicked on the link and got error 503 (service unavailable)

Comment: i'll just add the problem in my question wait

Comment: this line : t[i] = Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in )).readLine()); seems dodgy

Comment: try my solution mate, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object initialization is costly(i.e. using `new`). you should avoid that as much as you can). in this case you could create a `Scanner` object once and reuse it.

for example

```
class INTEST {
    public static void main(String...s) {
        String str = "";
         Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            str = input.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        String[] ar = str.split(" ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(ar[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(ar[1]);
        int count = 0;
        if (k <= 10000000) {
            int[] t = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
                try {
                    t[i] = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (t[i] <= 1000000000) {
                    if (t[i] % k == 0) count++;

                } else break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

NOTE:
there are still more optimization can be given to the code. for example using `nextInt` instead of `nextLine` then convert to `integer`. in addition you can always assume the input, you don't need to check for the value all the time.

Comment: thanks for your time mate , but as i mentioned in my question , i already gave Scanner a try but it won't work

Comment: there is hardly a difference between scanner and bufferReader. I believe your problem is creating new objects in the loop.

Comment: yeah ,  just changed that too , created Scanner object outside loop , and used the same object for parsing whole , but still it is showing Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: did you try reading integer instead of String (using nextInt instead_

Comment: one more thing, why do you need array t?

Comment: this "one more thing" DID IT :D   , even i don't know why i used array , simply use single variable and keep overwriting it  right ? i just needed to increment the counter and no need of the element thereafter .
thanks (y)

Comment: And hey buddy regarding you saying there is hardly any difference between Scanner and BufferedReader , just wanted to let you know that its still not working with Scanner , and CodeChef prefers i/o with bufferedreader as Scanner is convenient but SLOW comparatively for large inputs   http://www.codechef.com/wiki/java  :)

Comment: grants mate , that's true that scanner is slower, but for such problem I saw some accepted answer using Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final optimized solution that run successfully :)

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.io.*;

class INTEST{
public static void main(String... s) {
String str="";
try{
str = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
String[] ar = str.split(" ");

int n = Integer.parseInt(ar[0]);
int k = Integer.parseInt(ar[1]);
int count = 0;
if(k<=10000000){
int t=0;
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
try{
t  = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine()) ;
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

 if(t<=1000000000)  
{
if(t%k==0)
count++;
} 
else break;
}}

System.out.println(count);

}}
```